# How do refer an existing s3 bucket in my CFN template so that my lambda can use the bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, aws-cloudformation, serverless

I have a CFN template where in I am creating 2 s3 buckets for the image resizing using CloudFront.
the issue is that I want to use an already existing bucket from s3 for these functions.
but I get an error that s3 already exists when I provide the resource ARN and other data.
how can I resolve this?
I tried giving the details ARN name etc and tried deploying but it doesn't work

Comment: Difficult to help when we can't see the relevant parts of the template. If you want to use an existing S3 bucket then refer to it by ARN and don't attempt to create that bucket in your template.

Comment: thanks i'm new to CFN couldnt understand the template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would help you:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: 'CFN template example for referencing existing S3 bucket to lambda'
Parameters:
  myS3Bucket:
    Type: String
    Description: Provide the S3 bucket you want to referece into your lambda.
Resources:
  MyLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Description: A lambda function
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      Environment:
        Variables:
          S3_BUCKET: !Ref myS3Bucket
```